# Distance metric to compare statistical features extracted from 400 time series for time series clustering

Tags: time-series, clustering, descriptive-statistics, distance

I would like to cluster 400 car rental demand time series (small positive valued) based on the following 7 statistical features:

> entropy, number of mean crossings, 95th percentile, root mean squared,
> variance, kurtosis, max value

These features were shortlisted from around 20 statistical features after removing the highly correlated statistical features.

what is the correct distance metric to compare two sets of these statistical feature vectors? Currently, I standardize (mean=0,var=1) each of the feature so that they are comparable. Then, I use the euclidean distance to compute distances between standardized feature vectors.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Are there better distance metrices for these statistical features?